# Auto checkout Paypal API python or autoform

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, paypal

I want to make a program to make auto checkout on different website. For this I have already make a "add to cart" and a "live stock checker", now I need to do autocheckout. But I fail with 2 different options:

First one: I try to make a autoform on Paypal website to put my email adress and my password automatically but selenium return this error :

> selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"email"}
>     (Session info: chrome=51.0.2704.103)
>     (Driver info: chromedriver=2.22.397929 (fb72fb249a903a0b1041ea71eb4c8b3fa0d9be5a),platform=Mac OS X 10.11.5 x86_64)

My Python code is:

```
br = webdriver.Chrome()
br.get("http://www.adidas.fr/on/demandware.store/Sites-adidas-FR-Site/en_FR/Cart-MiniAddProduct?layer=Add+To+Bag+overlay&pid=S75148_620")
br.get("https://www.adidas.fr/on/demandware.store/Sites-adidas-FR-Site/en_FR/CODelivery-RedirectToPaypal")
time.wait(10000)  ##wait load page
br.find_element_by_id("email").send_keys("test@tes.com")
```

When I inspect element with Chrome I can find this on the html code :

```
<input id="email" name="login_email" type="email" class="hasHelp  validate validateEmpty  " required="required" aria-required="true" value="" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Email">
```

But when I do a right click + source code (on the Paypal login page) I can't find this lines. I think that why selenium return this error (but not sure).

The second option is the API paypal but I can't find informations to make autocheckout, I can only find informations about how to install API on your own website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please,i don't know how to do that and can't understand why selenium return this error , furthermore PAYPAL doc is too bad :/